# An inequality with absolute values

Tags: inequality

Please help me prove this inequality:

If $|a\pm b|\leq 1$ then $|a|+\frac{|b^2|}{2}\leq1$

Comment: Can't prove it, pick $a = 2$, $b = -2$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Or even $\;a=1,000\;,\;\;b=-999.5\;$ ...and infinite more counterexamples :)

Comment: Check the condition that I have added.

Comment: $b=\sqrt {b^2}\le\frac{b^2}{2}$.  Maybe you want it in the other direction.

Comment: Could you confirm that you mean $|a+b|\leq 1 \wedge |a-b|\leq 1$ (both conditions must be satisfied)?

Comment: In that case your "additional condition" is not necessary, as it is consequence of the previous inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming that you need both $|a+b|\leq 1$ and $|a-b|\leq 1$ to hold, otherwise the thesis is wrong.)

Suppose, without loss of generality, that $0\leq a$ and $0 \leq b$ (otherwise change signs).

We will first prove that $b\leq 1$: in fact, if $b>1$, then $b+a>b>1$ so the condition $|a+b|\leq 1$ would not hold. The same happens with $a$, so we have $0≤a≤1$ and $0≤b≤1$

Also, we have that $b≤1-a$ so 
$$
b^2≤(1-a)^2=1-2a+a^2 \\
b^2+2a-a^2≤1
$$
and, as $a^2 ≤ 1$,
$$
b^2+2a-a^2+a^2≤1+a^2 \\
b^2+2a≤1+a^2 \\
b^2+2a≤2
$$

This is exactly the inequality yo wanted to check, with the exception that we are not using absolute values because all the numbers were positive from the start.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is wrong since it does not hold for the case $a=1$ and $b=-1$. With this conditions we have $|a + b| = 0 < 1 $. however,

$ |a| + \frac{|b^2|}{2} = 1 + 1/2> 1 $

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the mistakes. Not that the condition is $|a\pm b|\leq 1$

Comment: This answer was okay, but the conditions have been changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: no, because in this case $|a-b|=2$ so it's not a counterexample.

Comment: Perhaps what you should do, @Spock, is stop changing the question every time someone reveals you it is wrong. Re-think carefully the conditions and then post.